# adding a UIView as a SubView to a custom class, subclass of UIView, Swift

Tags: class, swift, uiview, subclass, addsubview

I am having the following problem.
I have a custom class, subclass of UIView
Within it, I try to add a new UIView, but it's not letting me.

```
class myCustomViewClass: UIView {

let smallerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

        self.view.addSubview(smallerView) // Error with this !

}
```

I have tried different things.
I know I can make it work if I subclass from UIViewController instead, but I don't really want to do that.

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: `UIView` has no property named `view`. you should just call `self.addSubview:` instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
class myCustomViewClass: UIView {

   let smallerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
       self.addSubview(smallerView) 
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Also, DON'T DO THIS - `drawRect` (or `draw` in later versions of Swift) will be called repeatedly, and should not be overridden unless you're actually handling drawing of your view yourself. It's certainly not the place to be calling `addSubView`